# Where a session object is maintained? OR who manages a session object?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

Where a session object is maintained? OR who manages a session object?

1. `Servlet container`
2. `ServletContext`
3. `ServletConfig`
4. `HttpRequest`

Answer (score -1):

These two links will surely help you, I can bet on it.Please go through !By the way it's the Container who sees all of session related things.

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html

https://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-session-management-servlet-httpsession-url-rewriting

Comment: edited the answer to answer user's primary question.